# wicked gem - add steps dynamically based on previous selections

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wicked-gem

How it it possible to implement a wicked gem wizzard and add steps dynamically:
- first step => select country
- second step => select select city
- other step => display shops listsbased on the previous 2 selections.

It seems like we can add it like this in the controller:

```
before_action :set_steps
before_action :setup_wizard
...
private
def set_steps
  if params[:flow] == "twitter"
    self.steps = [:ask_twitter, :ask_email]
  elsif params[:flow] == "facebook"
    self.steps = [:ask_facebook, :ask_email]
  end
end
```

But I wonder if it is possible not create a new array of steps but adding the new ones to the previous ones, e.g.:

```
self.steps << Shop.some_query_based_on_country_and_city
```

More of that, in all the examples you know exactly the step names and their content, so you have a page per step. How to do if the content is the same but there are à lot of identical content steps (for example questions to answer)?

Any idea ? Thank you.